# com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.PermanentBackendException: Unexpected interrupt

Tags: titan

After upgrading to Titan 1.0.0 I started to see the following exceptions under load, using Cassandra (2.2.6) as the storage backend:

```
Caused by: java.lang.InterruptedException: sleep interrupted
       at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)[:1.8.0_102]
       at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Thread.java:340)[:1.8.0_102]
       at
java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.sleep(TimeUnit.java:386)[:1.8.0_102]
       at
com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.util.time.TimestampProviders.sleepPast(TimestampProviders.java:138)
       at
com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.common.DistributedStoreManager.sleepAfterWrite(DistributedStoreManager.java:222)
       ... 66 more
```

Can this be fixed through configuration? 
While there are several configuration items available around timestamps, I did not find any that strikes me as relevant to the timestamp provider itself.

Answer (score 2):

You should check your Cassandra logs. I have found that Titan under load starts to throw these types of errors as well as Timeout errors when Cassandra starts its [compaction](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/dml/dml_write_path_c.html#concept_ds_wt3_32w_zj__dml-compaction) process.

Grep for the keyword "GC" in `/var/log/cassandra/system.log` monitor your disk usage using dstat. If you see "GC" often then you under going heavy compaction and this bogs down titan.

To get around this you can try to optimise how you load your data into titan so as to not cause compaction to often.

**The following are just things we tried that worked for our case:**

1. Avoid deletions. Deletions trigger tombstoning which leads to compaction.
2. Increase the size of your JVM. One of the things which causes compaction to run is when you start to run out of memory so this makes it less likely to run.
3. You can try to use different [compaction strategies](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/operations/ops_configure_compaction_t.html). Each one is optimised for a different use case.

Comment: Compactions are part of normal C* operation. Every node will perform compactions in the end. If Titan does not handle a normal operational state of its persistence backend I would say this is a bug?

Comment: Possibly, but I honestly have not looked too far into it. I think it's an oversight. Or rather poor handling of failures. My suspicion is because the out of date Astyanax drivers don't handle things nicely which prohibits titan from handling it nicely. But I am not sure.